# Taking long time executing complex mySql query

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, execution

My query looks like this:

```
$result_portlist=mysql_query("
    SELECT 
        portfolio AS the_port,
        SUM(balance * course) AS the_balance,
        SUM(insurance * course) AS the_insurance
        FROM banks_all 
    WHERE CONCAT(balance, insurance)!='0'
    GROUP BY portfolio
    ",$db);

$myrow_portlist=mysql_fetch_array($result_portlist); 
if(mysql_num_rows($result_portlist)>0) { 
    do { 
        echo '<span> value1, vaule2, value3...</span>';

        $result_portlist1=mysql_query("
            SELECT 
                department AS the_department,
                SUM(balance * course) AS the_balance,
                SUM(insurance * course) AS the_insurance
            FROM banks_all 
            WHERE CONCAT(balance, insurance)!='0'
                AND portfolio='$myrow_portlist[the_port]' 
            GROUP BY department
        ",$db);

        $myrow_portlist1=mysql_fetch_array($result_portlist1); 
        if (mysql_num_rows($result_portlist1)>0) { 
            do { 
                echo '<span> value1, vaule2, value3...</span>'

                $result_portlist2=mysql_query("
                    SELECT 
                        manager_name AS the_manager,
                        SUM(balance * course) AS the_balance,
                        SUM(insurance * course) AS the_insurance
                    FROM banks_all
                    WHERE CONCAT(balance, insurance)!='0'
                        AND portfolio='$myrow_portlist[the_port]' 
                        AND department='$myrow_portlist1[the_department]'
                    GROUP BY manager_name
                ",$db);

                { 
                    do {
                        echo '<span> value1, vaule2, value3...</span>';
                    } while ($myrow_portlist2=mysql_fetch_array($result_portlist2));
                } 
            } while ($myrow_portlist1=mysql_fetch_array($result_portlist1)); 
        } 
    } while ($myrow_portlist1=mysql_fetch_array($result_portlist1)); 
}
```

So this query takes hours to execute for table with 40,000+ rows with hundreds of combinations of `portfolio`+`department`+`manager_name`. What I thought was to make one query at start that would group values by `manager_name` and then let php group `portfolio` and `department`. After creating this query, my mind has just blown up and has no free memory left to think :)

Please advice me how to rearrange this query or how to simplify it to take less time to execute.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: here is image, how my table (with nested tables) look like:

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFqRg.jpg)

Comment: Try to combine the queries where possible

Comment: From a first glance it looks like you could use one query (using joins) to collect all your data. All 3 tables seem to be joined by just 2 fields, so it should not be that difficult.

Comment: Thanks for answers. But instead of `<span>` I got a complex table that will show total values for `portfolio` then when i click the specific `portfolio`, it will open nested table grouped by `department` and when i click the specific `department`, it will open nested table grouped by `manager_name`. would JOIN help in this case?

Comment: So do an EXPLAIN on the query to see how MySQL is actually executing it, and show us the table structures with details of any indexes on those tables

Comment: @user3137740 So you want to load the data of the nested tables already at the start? I would put such nested stuff in a separate AJAX request and just load on demand. This will reduce the amount of data to transfer drastically.

Comment: AJAX would be solution! I am newbie in AJAX+Jquery, but I think its worth to try.

Comment: I've edited you code to make it clearer, and to understand one part... Turns out that what was hitching me is that there's a set of { } that are completely useless around the last do while loop... I left it as is, but they shouldn't have any reason for staying.

Comment: The AJAX solution would not make the query faster... For each query launched (about a 110 with 10 ports in 10 departments) you would need 110 HTTP requests. It is way better to cut off on requests than first page load time... But in any case, showing 40,000 lines of database in a simple HTML table is to be avoided.

Comment: AJAX did the job for me, I made `portfolio` query and when user clicks specific portfolio, AJAX will load `department` and `manager_name` pretty quickly for one `portfolio`. The problem was that query for 30-40 `portfolios` was too much, so making query for 1 `portfolio` did great job. Thank you everyone who helped me with this problem. I also ticked the answer below as correct one, because it is the correct answer for the question I asked, but I didn't use that method because of 'complexity' of my table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it takes a lot of time is because you are executing a massive amount of queries... Let's say you have 10 portfolios, in 10 departments, you'd make 100 queries. This amount is insane, and reducing the number of queries is pretty simple in your case.

I would simply grab all the data in one query, and use a 3 level group by with a rollup:

```
$result=mysql_query("
    SELECT 
        portfolio AS the_port,
        department AS the_department,
        manager_name AS the_manager,
        SUM(balance * course) AS the_balance,
        SUM(insurance * course) AS the_insurance
    FROM banks_all 
    WHERE 
        CONCAT(balance, insurance)!='0'
    GROUP BY 
        portfolio,
        department,
        manager_name 
    with ROLLUP
    ORDER BY the_port,the_department,the_manager;
",$db);
echo '<table>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    if($row['the_port'] === null){
        //This is the big total row... Let's skip it for now shall we?
        continue;
    }
    echo '<tr>';
    if($row['the_department'] === null){
        echo '<td>Portfolio: '.$row['the_port'].'</td>';
    }else{
        if($row['the_manager'] === null){
            echo '<td>Department: '.$row['the_port'].'</td>';
        }else{
            echo '<td>Manager: '.$row['the_port'].'</td>';
        }
    }
    echo '<td>'.$row['the_balance'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['the_insurance'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

This query will return all lines grouped by portfolio then grouped by department, then grouped by manager. This would return all rows from the finest point (your third while) but with `ROLLUP` you will also get a row for the other group by levels. This is exactly as if you would have done `GROUP BY portfolio,department` and `GROUP BY portfolio` inside the same query.

In the rolled up rows, the value of the keys omitted from the group by will be NULL. So you can easily check on `the_manager`, when it's null it means you have the full department, when `the_department` is null you have the full portfolio.

Comment: WOOOW! It looks exactly what I need. I'll go ahead and try this now. Will report when I test it.

Comment: Well, I tested it, but I can't separate rows for the table i have (see the image). **In the rolled up rows, the value of the keys omitted from the group by will be NULL. So you can easily check on the_manager, when it's null it means you have the full department, when the_department is null you have the full portfolio.** - I forgot to try this part...

Comment: I have edited my answer, adding an order by statement and some php code to display something similar to what you would like.